# Find the Schmidt decomposition

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, bilinear-form

How can I find the Schmidt decomposition of the following state of two qubits

$$|
\psi\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle|0\rangle+|0\rangle|1\rangle+|1\rangle|0\rangle}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

i.e I want to find the ortonormal states $\{ |\alpha_{i}\rangle\}$ and $\{ |\beta_{i}\rangle\}$ such that

$$
|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}|\alpha_{i}\rangle|\beta_{i}\rangle
$$

where $\lambda_{i}$ are the Schmidt coefficients.

I proved to add and subtract the same terms to rearrange $|\psi\rangle$ into combinations of $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle - |1\rangle$ but I don't find a coherent solution.

Note: $\langle0|0\rangle=\langle1|1\rangle=1$, $\langle0|1\rangle=0$, are two ortonormal vectors usually used in quantum mechanics.

Comment: You have solved the problem (here)[http://web.mit.edu/2.111/www/2010/ps3_2010Sol2.pdf].

Comment: Why isn't $|\psi \rangle$ not already written as a Schmidt decomposition?

Comment: @RafaBudría Hello, the link you posted says ''file not found"". Could you post the correct link? Thank you

Comment: @OfekGillon I do not understand what you say. I want to decompose $|\psi \rangle$ into Schmidt decomposition.

Comment: So why not just $\{ |0 \rangle , |1\rangle \}$ and $\{ |0 \rangle , |1\rangle \}$ as the basis?

Comment: @OfekGillon you have it in the main: i.e I want to find the ortonormal states $\{ |\alpha_{i}\rangle\}$ and $\{ |\beta_{i}\rangle\}$ such that

$$
|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}|\alpha_{i}\rangle|\beta_{i}\rangle
$$

where $\lambda_{i}$ are the Schmidt coefficients.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the syntax for a link. Now: http://web.mit.edu/2.111/www/2010/ps3_2010Sol2.pdf

Comment: @OfekGillon I do not understand where is the problem. But do not care about it, RafaBudría posted the solution in a pdf. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem when reading "quantum computation and quantum information". The idea is to start with

$
\psi = \sum_{ij}a_{ij}|i_A\rangle|j_B\rangle
$

for the composite system A and B. Then in our case,

$
a_{ij} = 1/\sqrt{3}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Then we can simply perform SVD for this matrix to get the desired Schmidt decompostition.